# How add a product to shopping cart with qty attatched.

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays

first of all, thank you for your time.

I need help with my cart system, I need to know how can i add a quantity to my array.

so if the user adds a product to the cart they select the quantity required. What is a good method of defining that quantity to the product they selected.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does your array currently look like? Can we have some code?

Comment: can you just decide what is your question about? **php**, **html**, **mysql**, **arrays**? I see no code here. And my guess your question is not about any of tags you put :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a full tutorial for exactly what you need:
http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/06/creating-simple-shopping-cart-with-php